How to use Python multiprocessing and subprocess to run Pytype on different files in parallel?
I have thousands of Python files to run PyType on, which will take months. Thus, I am trying to use Python multiprocessing to create multiple processes and use each process to run PyType on a separate file to speed up the running.
I've tried the following script, and I expect there to be N processes, each running PyType on one different file. However, I found that all processes run PyType on the same file instead of a different file.
I suspect that it is a problem with PyType's internal working mechanism, but, has anyone encountered similar problems?
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os

def work(cmd):
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return f"{os.getpid()} - Command: {cmd}\nOutput: {result.stdout}\nError: {result.stderr}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_dir = "xxx"
    cmds = []
    for file in os.listdir(my_dir):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            cmds.append(["pytype", "-o", os.path.join(my_dir, '.pytype'), os.path.join(my_dir, file)])
    count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=count) as pool:
        results = pool.map(work, cmds)
    for result in results:
        print(result)


Why do you have a subprocess inside your function?

You're mapping the function across all your processors and then you try launch subprocesses inside those function calls

I see, does it mean that all different processors actually use the same subprocess?

No; why would they? I don't really get the question you're asking but you mapped the function out - its namespace will be copied over to all the processes you launched. Then you try launch more; Inception style

I don't see how each invocation of the pytype command would be executing against the same .py file given the code you posted. I would recommend for debugging purposes that you modify worker function work to just return the python filename being passed to it as in the following code. I also suggest that you use a multithreading pool instead of a multiprocessing pool. There is no point in creating processes whose only processing consists of executing the subprocess command, which creates another process. I would also use the imap method to lazily create all the commands required and to print the results without having to create the cmds and results lists.
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import get_ident
import subprocess
import os

def work(cmd):
    # Just return the .py file name for debugging purposes.
    # Delete the following line for actual processing:  
    return cmd[-1]
    
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return f"{get_ident()} - Command: {cmd}\nOutput: {result.stdout}\nError: {result.stderr}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_dir = "xxx"
    output_dir = os.path.join(my_dir, '.pytype')
    cmds = (
        ["pytype", "-o", output_dir, os.path.join(my_dir, file)]
        for file in os.listdir(my_dir) if file.endswith(".py")
    )

    n_processors = os.cpu_count()
    with ThreadPool(processes=n_processors) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(work, cmds):
            print(result)

Let me know if the debugging code is printing the same filename repeatedly.
